# "sentinels" and "slaves" in redis sentinel info never decrease

Tags: redis, middleware, redis-sentinel

A redis cluster with one master node and two replica nodes. There are three sentinels to monitor the master node.
sentinel config is follow:

```
protected-mode no
bind 0.0.0.0
port 26380
daemonize yes
appendonly yes
pidfile "/var/run/sentinel.pid"
logfile "/data/log/redis/sentinel.log"

dir "/data"
sentinel deny-scripts-reconfig yes
sentinel monitor local-master *.*.*.* 16379 2

sentinel down-after-milliseconds local-master 3000
sentinel auth-pass local-master ***
```

when the sentinels start one by one, "slaves" normally increases to 3.

```
127.0.0.1:26380> info sentinel
# Sentinel
sentinel_masters:1
sentinel_tilt:0
sentinel_tilt_since_seconds:-1
sentinel_running_scripts:0
sentinel_scripts_queue_length:0
sentinel_simulate_failure_flags:0
master0:name=local-master,status=ok,address=*.*.*.*:16379,slaves=2,sentinels=3
```

When I shutdown one sentinels, "+sdown sentinel" in sentinel log shows that this action. However, the "slaves" doesn't decrease, it remains at 3.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxodF.png)

It's same for shutting down replica node.
Why? Could anyone help me find the problem?

"sentinels" and "slaves" info can be normally decrease when shutting down.